# Ubuntu 12.04 failed to reboot after unsuccessful update done on 28/8/2013

Tags: 12.04, boot, dual-boot, grub2, samsung

1. I was updating kernel, mesa, firefox, thunderbird, python and some other packages on 28/8/2013. My internet connection terminated while updates were ongoing. So Laptop did not started in next reboot.
2. I read all post regarding editing grub menu and setting nomodeset option along with other options but none of them worked for me.

   Except `quiet splash nomodeset vga=0×31` and `quiet splash i915.modeset=1` gave me front booting screen, but no avail,like dots moving in a front screen of Ubuntu... It did not bootup though. Only option was <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> when I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> it starts booting...it shows dots moving...but since it is rebooting, it does not load Ubuntu.
3. when I pressed <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, command line shows up, when i tried to run firefox from command-line, it shows message: 
   no display specified
   x11 initiallization failed
4. I tried to run in failsafe graphic mode but got error message as:

   ```
   xinit/;unable to run server /usr/bin/x
   non integer argument  /usr/shre/xdiagnose/failsafeserver:line 87: [ -lt:unary operator expected
   gdm:unrecognized service
   stop:unknown instance:
   xinit /usr/share/xdiagnose/failsafe

   xinit /etc/x11/xorg.conf.failsafe with- -- /usr/bin/x -br -once -config 
   /etc/x11/xorg.conf.failsafe -logfile
   /var/log/Xorg.failsafe.log

   xinit:unable to run server "/usr/bin/X" no such file or directory
   ```

   P.S. But I checked at `/usr/bin/Xorg` I found server is present there
5. Error message in `/var/log/syslog` :
       ACPI _OSC request failed, returned control mask:0x1d
6. Not able to boot from LiveCD: 
   When I tried to boot from pendrive, laptop shows a blank screen with blinking cursor, after waiting for 15 min, no progress so hard reset.
7. Don't suggest me to replace Ubuntu 12.04.
8. My laptop configuration is: Samsung NP300E5Z, 4GB RAM, Intel i5 2nd generation with inbuilt graphics 3000 series, Windows7 and ubuntu12.04 in dual boot mode.
9. I am able to login to Windows without any problem, so I think it is not Grub problem.

I checked almost 40 posts and related discussion, but none of them worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

**Try following steps once to fix your problem**

- When your system starts press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to go to CLI `tty1`, login using your credentials.
- Then execute following commands in series, i,e one after another:

  ```
  sudo apt-get autoremove
  sudo apt-get autoclean
  sudo apt-get --purge remove $(dpkg -l | grep "^rc" | awk '{print $2}' | tr '\n' ' ')
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get -f install
  sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
  sudo apt-get upgrade
  ```
- If everything goes fine then reboot your system and check whether it solves your issues. Run this command to reboot your system:

  ```
  sudo reboot
  ```

---

**You can also give a try to fix your problem using Safe Mode if above method doesn't help you**

- When your system starts chose **Recovery Mode** (*2nd option* in grub menu).
- From the Menu just go to **Grub** option, it will give a message like **Updating grub will mount your system in read/write mode**. Just chose **yes** to mount your system in read/write mode. It will update your grub and will exit from **Grub** menu.
- chose **network** option it may enable your network.
- Then chose **dpkg** menu from the list, chose **yes** for all.
- Finally chose **root** option and login. Execute following commands one after another:

  ```
    apt-get autoremove
    apt-get autoclean
    apt-get --purge remove $(dpkg -l | grep "^rc" | awk '{print $2}' | tr '\n' ' ')
    apt-get update
    apt-get -f install
    apt-get dist-upgrade
    apt-get upgrade
  ```

  Then reboot your system and check whether your are able to use Ubuntu or not. Run this command to reboot:

  ```
    reboot
  ```

Hope either of this method works for you.. Reply if something goes wrong.

Comment: Thanks saurav.
I tried to execute all commands but I am not able to connect to internet. I tried with photon data card, mobile tethering but no help.

Comment: Then what happened? Can you provide some extra information?

Comment: I have mention all my tried methods in question. You need extra info about??

Comment: Have you tried my suggestion at least once? All the commands I have mentioned will fix broken packages, try to download missing packages, update your system to new packages, try to fix unmet dependencies, and hence `try to fix your system!`

Comment: At last reinstallation of ubuntu was inevitable so reinstalled ubuntu.

Comment: @OpenSourceEnthu: The only problem was the connection to the Internet. If you were able to connect to the Internet then you would be able to solve the issue. **In safe mode wired network always works.** I wish you don't get any trouble this time. :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, Ubuntu had deactivated networking, so one must access the command line and do the following steps:

1. mount read/write
2. enable networking
3. run all the commands to update and upgrade

Here are the commands, do them one after another:

```
sudo mount -o remount,rw /
sudo service networking start
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get upgrade
```