# DELL Inspiron 5537 hungups during boot

Tags: boot, dell, inspiron

I purchased a Inspiron 5537 with UBUNTU preinstalled.
Starting the lap-top, I followed all the instructions for UBUNTU. At the end I decided to accept all the proposed updates in UBUNTU.

Now the system hungups during boot and never goes to desktop.
Is there any way to recover that problem???

Comment: There's a good [thread][1] for fixing issues related to boot issues


  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems with my laptop. It`s possible that upgraded propertiary driver conflicts with lightdm. To confirm that check if you can switch to tty1 after system hangs up. To do that press 
[Ctrl]+ [Alt]+ [F1]
then log in using your login and password. After that type

```
dmesg
```

and if at the end of output you see something like:

```
init: failsafe-x main process 1393 terminated with status 1
```

then try this answer: [I get `failsafe-x main process terminated with status 1` while login, how to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343639/i-get-failsafe-x-main-process-terminated-with-status-1-while-login-how-to-fix)

Hope that will be helpful.