# Upgrade to 13.10, upgrade app halted

Tags: upgrade, 13.10

I'm trying to upgrade to 13.10, and the upgrader/installer app has stopped. It doesn't seem to be frozen- it gives me a warning if I try to quit it, but it has been stuck like this for hours now.

[image: the halted installer app]

The internet connection is fast and working. Am I going to break things horribly if I quit it and restart?

Comment: It seems that its completed and and stuck while restarting the system. You should restart your system. If you get any problem I'm sure [this link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/203301/how-to-safely-upgrade-from-an-older-ubuntu-version-to-a-newer-one/360486#360486) will definitely help you.

Comment: @SauravKumar I followed your suggestion and now my system won't boot past the screen where you select which OS to use.

Comment: Can you open your system in `Recovery Mode`? If yes then [this link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/340821/ubuntu-12-04-failed-to-reboot-after-unsuccessful-update-done-on-28-8-2013/340834#340834) 2nd option would help you.. If not then I think you've to repair your `Boot-Entry` i,e `grub-menu` through [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) give it a try..

Comment: @SauravKumar Yeah that's what I did (like I said in my answer). Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Short Answer

At least for my case, it turns out you can force a restart and then repair packages.

### Details

I followed @SauravKumar's advice in the comments and forced the system to restart. On reboot, the computer got to the purple screen where it selects which OS to run. If I chose the default Ubuntu, it started loading and then went to a black screen and didn't respond to the keyboard at all.

So I then booted in recovery mode and chose the check packages option. It found out that I was using a different version of `etc/default/rcs` than the package maintainer. I chose to update it (the default is don't update) and then resumed booting and now it's running fine. Just to make sure, I rebooted again, and it works after a regular reboot too.

Update to 13.10: success!

Comment: Anyone know what exactly happened here? I mean it seems like that `rcs` file got corrupted somehow, but why just that one, and why would it break everything?

Comment: Good!! And what about your system? Also mention that your system was upgraded to `13.10` or not? :)

Comment: Oh right, I thought I did haha.

Comment: Now it will help others to get through their problem.