# Monitor extremely dark after installation of 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, monitor, vga

The monitor becomes dark after some time in a working session or during the booting. Impossible to work. I must restart the laptop: 
(Thinkpad T400 videocard VgA Compatibile.) I don't have an external monitor.

This problem started after the upgrade from  14.04 LTS to 16.04 LTS. I uploaded missing drivers. I reinstalled Ubuntu. The problem is still there.  Now I suspect the hardware may be broken.

What can I do?

Comment: Hope this [link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/100232/how-do-i-change-the-grub-boot-order) will be useful for analysis of problem.

Comment: corrected link [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/340821/ubuntu-12-04-failed-to-reboot-after-unsuccessful-update-done-on-28-8-2013) will be useful, ignore previous comment.

Comment: Is there anyway that you can test your theory that your hardware is broken by finding a cheap monitor to plug into? Such as one from EBay.

Comment: If you dual-boot with Windows, does it work OK there?

Answer (score 0):

Worst case scenario IS that your PC has defective Hardware, Try doing a fresh install (not an upgrade, those never work, matter of fact the last time i did an upgrade i lost all my data, never trust upgrades to be safe) with a usb stick. if the problem persists i suspect your monitor light bulb is either burning or some kind of damage has been done.
hope this helps

Comment: If you've had a problem with Ubuntu upgrades, then your system probably had some problem BEFORE you started the upgrade. Of course, I'd ALWAYS recommend good backups before a major upgrade (not update) just in case something does go wrong.

Comment: upgrades are unsafe 4/5 times came with major issues