# Blank screen blinking after upgrading restart finishing the upgrade<solved>

Tags: boot

I get this blank screen with a blinking cursor in my Ubuntu 17.10 , however when I press the shift and go to grub as suggested I get the same blinking cursor after the text GRUB.

Comment: check whether you are facing same issues as mention in: https://askubuntu.com/questions/340821/ubuntu-12-04-failed-to-reboot-after-unsuccessful-update-done-on-28-8-2013, solution is also suggested, give it a try.

Comment: ah i fogot to edit , the problem was solved by reinstalling the Grub using liveUSB